# What are the necessary requirements to make this composite monad rewrite work?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

It is well known that if you want to take two monads and compose them and get a third monad, you need a distributive law.  Let us suppose we have this.  So, we have two monads

$$\mathcal{M}$$

And

$$\mathcal{C}$$

Such that,

$$\mathcal{M}  = \langle  M, \mu_M , \eta_M   \rangle$$

$$\mathcal{C}  = \langle  C, \mu_C , \eta_C   \rangle$$

And they admit a distributive law so that their composite $\mathcal{CM}$ forms a monad like this

$$\mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{M} =
\mathcal{CM}$$

$$\mathcal{CM} = \langle  CM, \mu_{CM} , \eta_{CM}   \rangle$$

I will discuss this notation below.

Next, suppose you have a monad map like this:

$$F: \mathcal{M}  \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$$

What special properties need to be satisfied in order to freely (and I'm not sure what I mean by freely) do the following rewrite from one composite monad to another like this?:

$$ I \otimes F : \mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{M} 
 \rightarrow  \mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{D} 
 $$

Where $I$ is an identity monad map.

Obviously, I mean that under this rewrite, $\mathcal{C} \otimes \mathcal{D}$  is a monad.  The composite functor $CD$ forms a monad:

$$ \mathcal{CD} =  \langle  CD, \mu_{CD} , \eta_{CD}   \rangle$$

In what sense, if any, is this notation, borrowed from monoidal categories, justified?  One might also ask, under what special conditions is the monoidal notation justified?  This might be like asking "when is there a composite monad?".  Perhaps there is a better way to phrase this, and it may be something like, "when does a set of monads form a monoid under monad composition?".  If this is well phrased, then has it been studied?  I think the problem here is that there is no general understanding of when a set of monads forms a monoid.  It is an equivalent problem to ask for general prescriptions of when a pair of monads can be composed.  That problem is [being worked out](https://events.illc.uva.nl/llama/slides/zwart-2022.pdf)
and it is very difficult.  Zwaart has done work to give broad classes of examples where composition is guaranteed.  Perhaps one can say that, if you can prove you live in one of those classes, you get a monoid over monads.  An example might be, suppose that in the algebraic theory for your monads, terms can be separated, then if all your monads live in a class like this, then you can have a monoid of monads.  Is this true or workable at all?

Comment: You mention a "distributive law" for monads, but don't give the definition or a name for it. Hint: you need to change  $C M C M$ into $C C M M$ to compose with the rest of the structure.

Comment: If both monads can be split to composition of two adjoint functors, $M \cong GF$ and $C \cong HK$, then $CMCM  \cong HKGFHKGF$. $CCMM  \cong HKHKGFGF \cong  HKGF \cong CM$. If $FH \cong I$ and $GK \cong I$, then these are all isomorphic.

Comment: @EsaPulkkinen, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447178/what-are-the-necessary-requirements-to-make-this-composite-monad-rewrite-work#comment1165895_447178), do you mean to ask that $K G$ be isomorphic to $I$?  I don't see any obvious occurrences of $G K$.

Comment: @LSpice look at how CMCM expands. Once you use $FH \cong I$, there is $GK$ which can be reduced by applying the other iso. I is the identity functor.

Comment: @EsaPulkkinen hi, did you want to answer and get the bounty?  I can put up a 200 point bounty for a long, detailed answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a sufficient, but not (necessarily, excuse the play on words) necessary condition:

If you also have a distributive law $\mathcal{D} \rightsquigarrow \mathcal{C}$, and the monad morphism $\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{D}$ is compatible with it in an appropriate way, this works. Let me expand.

You assume given monads $(\mathcal{C}, \eta^\mathcal{C}, \mu^\mathcal{C})$, $(\mathcal{M}, \eta^\mathcal{M}, \mu^\mathcal{M})$, and a distributive law $\sigma^\mathcal{M} : \mathcal{M} \rightsquigarrow \mathcal{C}$, that is, a natural transformation $\mathcal{M} \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}$ that makes [these diagrams](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZARgBoAGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQAdDgW3pwAsAxk2ABZAL4ACLrwHDGwAMLiQ40uky58hFGQBM1Ok1bsZfISOXSe5+WJVqN2PASLkKhhizaJONuSIS1rIWCkFmAQrKquogGM7abqTEnsY+fiF24f6hSlIRuRIxTlquKO4GNF4mvgV2VnWB+TlZDrHxpTrIeh5VaaYtTcG2ls2Zo8Vxmi5dPSl93gPjUWMjYauReZMdM0Q9lUaLtYMrw5sNJ-bb04koAKy9hzUZa-ZnudGOUwllyA8H1XSjVOwKuXx2t2QABZkqkji9NkVwTdfgA2WELZ6gz6GGBQADm8CIoAAZgAnCDcJDuEA4CBIMggRj0ABGMEYAAUUToQFgwNhYCBMUCONh8bwAHqgpGxcmUpA9Wn0xAAZhozLZnO57DJWHx-BwQqeIuWby4Ysl0rapIpVNVNDpSBhTNZ7K5Px5uv1huFAwt9Cll2ypplNvliAeSqQ6ONfr1lqDGw+1pAcrtMcdiAA7L7jqaLv7AyGU2mFQ7lTTAUtmEXXsHXp9ZbaneWGbmEcngjWrZNSxHW4gaRq3drfF6DUaq3m62Nu5dG2G7Tmo4hGVOMnP80nWkbh1qPTq9ROvn2ABwDgCc6td+867D5ArY7fN8YDPZPzdXNMz59j08RzQwDgb7ziWn7EN+ypXi6mruneY5Hj6f5+EBIFbu8O4fuGxCMj+16waOIDjkh65cKhtYARhExYXaOGXs+oHWOR76UOIQA) commute.

Let's call the other distributive law $\sigma^\mathcal{D} : \mathcal{D} \rightsquigarrow \mathcal{C}$ (it will make analogous diagrams commute). What we need for your "composition homomorphism" to be well-defined is for the monad morphism $\phi : \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{D}$ to satisfy a sort of [naturality condition](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRAB12BbOnACwDGjYAFkAvgAJOPfkIbAAwmJBjS6TLnyEUZAIxVajFm2m9BwpVO5m5o5avXY8BIrvIH6zVog7XZwgBFJU395JRU1EAwnLVdSfWpPYx8Q8zDgvzTgIJUDGCgAc3giUAAzACcILiQyEBwIJDcQBjoAIxgGAAUNZ20QcqwCvhwQRKNvX2wCngA9VNtxCLLK6sQAJmp6pABmMa8TdinZ+cD7SIqqms2G9b3k3zQ+LCsZLPCHEAvVpq3EXcN9ilMrZLJxHlhcmIgA). Let's work through why.

First, recall the definition of the Godement product of natural transformations $\phi, \psi \mapsto \phi \star \psi$ (aka the horizontal composition in the 2-category $\mathbf{Cat}$ of categories).

The monad structure on $\mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}$ is given by

$$\eta^{\mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}} : \mathbf{Id} \xrightarrow{\eta^\mathcal{C} \star \eta^\mathcal{M}} \mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}$$

The multiplication is where the distributive law comes into play:

$$\mu^{\mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}} : \mathcal{C} \mathcal{M} \mathcal{C} \mathcal{M} \xrightarrow{\mathcal{C} \sigma^\mathcal{M} \mathcal{M}} \mathcal{C} \mathcal{C} \mathcal{M} \mathcal{M} \xrightarrow{\mu^\mathcal{C} \star \mu^\mathcal{D}} \mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}$$

This yields the monad structure $(\mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}, \eta^{\mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}}, \mu^{\mathcal{C} \mathcal{M}})$. An identical argument for $\mathcal{D}$ yields $(\mathcal{C} \mathcal{D}, \eta^{\mathcal{C} \mathcal{D}}, \mu^{\mathcal{C} \mathcal{D}})$.

Now, we are assuming given a monad morphism $\phi : \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{D}$, that is a natural transformation making [this diagram](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZARgBoAGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQAdDgW3pwAsAxk2ABZAL4hxpdJlz5CKMgCZqdJq3ZdeA4Y2AARSdNnY8BIuVLE1DFm0SceffgCMAZsACSUYzJAYZgpEyhS2Gg5OOkIiEgAE2i56Yn6m8hYooao0dpqOiboiRgnOhfpGUmowUADm8ESg7gBOENxIoSA4EEhW6vZaHDA49AB6BTH6ElL+za3tNF1IZCCM9K4wjAAKcuaKIE1YNfw4IDkRA0Oj48kVJiCzbYi9i4jLuZFcaPxYpytrG9sghkQFgwNhYNNGi1HgBmBbdRAAFjO-XyHC+WBKcGGTRKGN+q3WWx2wUcoPBbDuDyQcM6CN6hIBJOBByOJxReSizDGpQmKUh92hSGRdKWHI+PG51yKxko4iAA) commute${}^1$. What we want is the natural transformation

$$\mathcal{C} \phi : \mathcal{C} \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{C} \mathcal{D}$$

to also be a monad morphism. To check this works, look at [this diagram](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBoBGAXVJADcBDAGwFcYkQAdDgW3pwAsARgDNgASSgBfEJNLpMufIRTlSxanSat2XXgIDGTYAFlps+djwEiqgEwaGLNok48+-Q42AARM3JAYlkpEtmoOWs6ueh5GAMKSAAS67p4mfhaK1iih9jSO2i7JBnGJRTFevjL+gZnKyADMYXkROm7FXvFJbeXAnWWpplUZVnWNuZpOrdGpfd0zpXNGleYBCiNEACxNEwVRKSVd0wf9RqaH+16DKzXrKFvj+ZEnHQtHL+ftPq8XX0OrQVlkABWbaPKY-WZvNIfHqQn5XaprYIoEEPFqFRbvZ5fGHzXFLMwaGBQADm8CIoGEACcINwkGQQDgIEhVDsnhwYDh6AA9bEIyk0umIBlMpChECMeiCGCMAAKSKyICpWBJ-BwIGakwxnJ52OW-mptJZNFFiEabNaOt5mN630+-JAhqF4tNWwlUpl8oByiVKrVGot2q51qhcM++oFRrNJuZiDdkulcoVPqwYGwsADYIxoYWaH4WD+TuNjNj4oTnuT7FT6bYmt2XDzBZWRcQIJLSHN5aT3vYytV6rr7O4zBDELtPQdLYAbDGkG6s1ER9iwz0I47BUg26aZ4G9p8V3iG-mA12vbUq2msBnmxvEAB2Wetwfg-fjw88Jc2wY0U+Vlx9-0byjAAOR8dwXZc32OD9R3DdJ1yjB920QUD3UTM9bhAasr1rXdIPxd4AAojywLo4C5KkukbABKQtbwATkfJDfx7f8-QHPCbVmbASV4WCJygy54JbcgRVjVCIK4hYeL4vVBN+IChUY5DROfFxiKkqj82osiKISDScy0rBaJ-D1u3PFxsOvA0GMfc1pTAKAkAAWinBlJOHblgHwvlJGE29VOQt0HKcxA3NM9C-19ftM3RRcvJ8m1fH8qMxI7GgQqQO94zMjDkWi-01NcK1vM03yUqFNK4wymBHJc7Kiq4ErEqhZKZEoSQgA):

- The cells with a bent arrow as one of the sides commute by definition
- the triangular cell all the way to the left commutes by (part of) our assumption that $\phi$ is a monad morphism
- the second to last cell from the right also commutes by (the other part of) our assumption that $\phi$ is a monad morphism
- The two square cells on the left commute by naturality of $\eta^\mathcal{C}$ and $\mu^\mathcal{C}$
- The only cell left is the one all the way to the right. You can factor that one [like this](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRAB12BbOnACwDGjYAGEAvgAJOPfkIajJ03oOEBZRd2Vzg6kGNLpMufIRRkAjFVqMWbJbOHipmh-Kf2V8gCIaZnnWJ6BiAY2HgERGQATFb0zKyIHC7+7snaqX7aPs6Zwj5BhmEmRObksTYJSbluvlpqta4KOXXyuvqFxhEopZbUcbaJHukN-tlDjiPabcGhnabIpTF9FXZpE82NY2s1G6OBYlYwUADm8ESgAGYAThBcSADM1DgQSGQgDHQARjAMAApG4VMICuWGOfBwIGW8VW1SanGwxx4AD1xq1JvUCiBrrckAAWJ4vRClazQwbbOHsBHI1HALaw3TUD7fP4A4qJEFgiHtLE3O6IACsBKQUUZXx+-yKXWBoPBkJJAyqLQpVLoKPJdKV+W52L5jxAzzxUIVNNSaD4WF2w0tGO1vMN+sJgvllRN6O8bopZqwmJ1ryFRKNLvJGSVpvN1rRcqZ4tZUo5sttOIDDuFgZhoY9Ic2Gi9UbFLMlQPjXIoYiAA). Now, the top square commutes by the "naturality" condition I referenced above, and the bottom one by interchange.

Hence $\mathcal{C} \phi$ is a monad morphism.

Edit: you mention being interested in further discussion, so here goes. What you would want for this to work for a larger class of (read: more than two) monads is not only distributive laws, but a coherent family of such. There is no wide consensus on what this should mean, but here are my two cents${}^2$.

Instead of talking about monads over a category, it's more appropriate to talk about [monads in a bicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#definition). The definition is exactly the one you're used to if the bicategory is a 2-category anyway (a monoid in the monoidal category of endo-1-cells on a given object), but the general case requires inserting appropriate unitors and associators in some places.

The reason for this digression is that we can encode monads in a bicategory $\mathcal{B}$ as lax 2-functors $* \to \mathcal{B}$. This [suggests](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#BicategoryOfMonads) defining the bicategory $\mathbf{Mnd}(\mathcal{B})$ of monads internal to $\mathcal{B}$ as the lax 2-functor bicategory

$$\mathbf{Mnd}(\mathcal{B}) := \mathbf{Lax}[*, \mathcal{B}]$$

[Even more is true](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+law#big_picture), though: distributive laws between monads in $\mathcal{B}$ are exactly monads in $\mathbf{Mnd}(\mathcal{B})$:

$$\mathbf{Dist}(\mathcal{B}) := \mathbf{Mnd}(\mathbf{Mnd}(\mathcal{B})) = \mathbf{Lax}[*, \mathbf{Lax}[*, \mathcal{B}]]$$

It's important to stress that, while the statement "monads are lax functors" is quite straightforward to see, the statement "distributive laws are monads in the bicategory of monads" requires some work to fully see.

You might be tempted to look for a "lax tensor-hom 2-adjunction", but (as far as I am aware, at least) there is no such thing. There's something similar we could do, but that's also a bit involved and outside the scope of this answer.

Now, you might be wondering, what is the point of all this? This allows us to state what a coherent family of distributive laws is: a pseudofunctor from a bicategory of "indices" $\mathcal{I}$ (whatever they might be, hopefully a sub-bi-category of $\mathbf{Mnd}(\mathcal{B})$) to our category of distributive laws

$$\mathcal{I} \to \mathbf{Dist}(\mathcal{B})$$

With all this out of the way, a (very important) disclaimer: the bicategory $\mathbf{Mnd}(\mathcal{B})$ is not what you might think it is. Its 1-cells are the more general morphisms of monads where the base 0-cell (category, in the case I discussed earlier) is not fixed.

But the things we know about distributive laws still apply (under suitable assumptions), and I strongly suspect that the argument I sketched at the beginning of this answer would be quite easy to generalize to this context.

To better expand on this last sentence, I would assume that the 1-cells in $\mathbf{Dist}(\mathcal{B})$ behave as I assumed $\phi$ to in the first part of the answer, or better yet in the correspondingly generalized way (at least for the more general notion of 1-cell of monads as a 2-natural transformation in $\mathbf{Lax}[*, \mathcal{B}]$). To be more explicit, I'm suggesting that such a $\phi$ would be a (special kind of?) 1-cell in $\mathbf{Dist}(\mathcal{B})$, in the case where $\mathcal{B} = \mathbf{Cat}$ and $\mathcal{I} = *$ so that we fix a single distributive law in the 2-category of categories.

As of now I don't have the time to go through all the details for this (since it would most likely take some time to unwind all these definitions). I will as soon as I have the time, since I find this stuff very interesting, but I'd also be thrilled to see someone else do it. There still are a few related interesting questions on the matter, to which I don't know the answer.

${}^1$: There's a more general notion of morphism of monads that doesn't fix the base category, but that's likely outside the scope of this question. A similar argument should apply to that case as well.

${}^2$: Calling this "my two cents" may be a bit reductive, since what I'm going to go through is the gist of my master's thesis, but still this is what I think "coherent family of distributive laws" should mean.